# Alexa device address API issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I have been facing issues running device address API skill.. these are my JSON input and outputs, please help me out. This is data I got for the sample code from Alexa's sample code github repository. I still can't figure what's wrong here.
This is the link - https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-node-device-address-api
JSON Input :

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "session": {
        "new": false,
        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.fe30659e-b123-48a4-97f1-d06d994cd92a",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.7d9b61a9-92ec-4765-84af-139e0318beed"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AG2EQ2ZKWM66DSNQU43PUMM7EC3AOSD5G4KTFXZW34PCDQKDOLQF4UAB4FSDPDS4PA2E26UJEUYOITKQO76WLKGLLJSYK65AH2XAQMSJIOWOAQDUZP7737ONHDVOIB7JWUP6JGR3DONODFL3EJRVWFAZ77PYFNVFLLE7TSJM3NPT2QK7BPGUV76WX7FJNGFTDXCPKGZC72NPCBI",
            "permissions": {
                "consentToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5hbWF6b25hbGV4YS5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJBbGV4YVNraWxsS2l0Iiwic3ViIjoiYW16bjEuYXNrLnNraWxsLjdkOWI2MWE5LTkyZWMtNDc2NS04NGFmLTEzOWUwMzE4YmVlZCIsImV4cCI6MTYyNjEwOTI1MSwiaWF0IjoxNjI2MTA1NjUxLCJuYmYiOjE2MjYxMDU2NTEsInByaXZhdGVDbGFpbXMiOnsiaXNEZXByZWNhdGVkIjoidHJ1ZSIsImNvbnNlbnRUb2tlbiI6IkF0emF8SXdFQklPek5pcFc5OW9USy1NcDlKRnc5b2F3aFd6NjZ3RGQ0YjdXSUlrekRDbEVlOEczU1pTcXpFVUtBVTdocFlUc0p6MU9HcVdsYnZrZXRWZWFneVFFMGFMZWhsTFBueUNqU2dhenBmdEpPR1d4ZHlrMERXWDh5YUs5WWVFTDZieDllbzg2b0NZRGtlUVV3dmJ5c0I1cHVQN3hVaTFFeW5jcjM5NFZKbHBTWTJvaXlMdmtwV1BrU0syZUxCNTRvR0RSS2M5dVluYmRGcUNlZ193YzB0clhtRFpyel9aN0ZGaEdvb2Y1dTh3N3ZuUVZYNUhMTVp1Vnp2UUVKTGxMZDNqdVRLTXQyY1paRU0wSmJ2aW5YNDdZRU5nSVkiLCJkZXZpY2VJZCI6ImFtem4xLmFzay5kZXZpY2UuQUZOTFc3MlFWUTVBUzdBWTdMREZMSlZQNkVUNlZOUjQzU0xSU0NETFVJVE0ySFZEQ1Q1STRLR1FYR1BTVlBLWk9ZVU5IVVkyUzM1WlVGVUdXS0RLNFlNQTdBU0RMVEdRWlZRREtDVUROSFBQTVVEQU9PWlVDUzYyRlZUQzYzWjYzUTdLNVFRSkJaVkg1TFNNMkc2V1VVVEozUFhRNElXTEpCVVNGWDNaT0dSU0lOWFZJUjY3SyIsInVzZXJJZCI6ImFtem4xLmFzay5hY2NvdW50LkFHMkVRMlpLV002NkRTTlFVNDNQVU1NN0VDM0FPU0Q1RzRLVEZYWlczNFBDRFFLRE9MUUY0VUFCNEZTRFBEUzRQQTJFMjZVSkVVWU9JVEtRTzc2V0xLR0xMSlNZSzY1QUgyWEFRTVNKSU9XT0FRRFVaUDc3MzdPTkhEVk9JQjdKV1VQNkpHUjNET05PREZMM0VKUlZXRkFaNzdQWUZOVkZMTEU3VFNKTTNOUFQyUUs3QlBHVVY3NldYN0ZKTkdGVERYQ1BLR1pDNzJOUENCSSJ9fQ.eYVBP80ovTiNhFn7kj9HS5-JT6VNJzr9-knzScYff-gRsLA-PfbC1Vq4RgUFRMFgsIdPhWQKFbgFodnMER9FVAkIy_qSb2pTWo1qe7h1DbmRWLOBcWw8-3fNDJOGqmC0GsnkHdmt82XMFlbbRZBtzt_Qbq1OC7i6bBS324SRM6MiaZC9DZpYlfqXuaYVhD2bcG3NzfVbb3LZirGRHDelrNfT_na0E2xNEFf4Qx5vfIvp9I5x0hxUh8Wch-gY0-iTt5GKFqe3-TZ8PRA7DeXr8CSM42nknzvzaBIYIWm3nQTYwbQxO4Fj9wJfeoXIO9_19tglLwI2MabLYQzGhqmJAw"
            }
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "Viewports": [
            {
                "type": "APL",
                "id": "main",
                "shape": "RECTANGLE",
                "dpi": 213,
                "presentationType": "STANDARD",
                "canRotate": false,
                "configuration": {
                    "current": {
                        "mode": "HUB",
                        "video": {
                            "codecs": [
                                "H_264_42",
                                "H_264_41"
                            ]
                        },
                        "size": {
                            "type": "DISCRETE",
                            "pixelWidth": 1280,
                            "pixelHeight": 800
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "Viewport": {
            "experiences": [
                {
                    "arcMinuteWidth": 346,
                    "arcMinuteHeight": 216,
                    "canRotate": false,
                    "canResize": false
                }
            ],
            "mode": "HUB",
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "pixelWidth": 1280,
            "pixelHeight": 800,
            "dpi": 213,
            "currentPixelWidth": 1280,
            "currentPixelHeight": 800,
            "touch": [
                "SINGLE"
            ],
            "video": {
                "codecs": [
                    "H_264_42",
                    "H_264_41"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Extensions": {
            "available": {
                "aplext:backstack:10": {}
            }
        },
        "System": {
            "application": {
                "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.7d9b61a9-92ec-4765-84af-139e0318beed"
            },
            "user": {
                "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AG2EQ2ZKWM66DSNQU43PUMM7EC3AOSD5G4KTFXZW34PCDQKDOLQF4UAB4FSDPDS4PA2E26UJEUYOITKQO76WLKGLLJSYK65AH2XAQMSJIOWOAQDUZP7737ONHDVOIB7JWUP6JGR3DONODFL3EJRVWFAZ77PYFNVFLLE7TSJM3NPT2QK7BPGUV76WX7FJNGFTDXCPKGZC72NPCBI",
                "permissions": {
                    "consentToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.eYVBP80ovTiNhFn7kj9HS5-JT6VNJzr9-knzScYff-gRsLA-PfbC1Vq4RgUFRMFgsIdPhWQKFbgFodnMER9FVAkIy_qSb2pTWo1qe7h1DbmRWLOBcWw8-3fNDJOGqmC0GsnkHdmt82XMFlbbRZBtzt_Qbq1OC7i6bBS324SRM6MiaZC9DZpYlfqXuaYVhD2bcG3NzfVbb3LZirGRHDelrNfT_na0E2xNEFf4Qx5vfIvp9I5x0hxUh8Wch-gY0-iTt5GKFqe3-TZ8PRA7DeXr8CSM42nknzvzaBIYIWm3nQTYwbQxO4Fj9wJfeoXIO9_19tglLwI2MabLYQzGhqmJAw"
                }
            },
            "device": {
                "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AFNLW72QVQ5AS7AY7LDFLJVP6ET6VNR43SLRSCDLUITM2HVDCT5I4KGQXGPSVPKZOYUNHUY2S35ZUFUGWKDK4YMA7ASDLTGQZVQDKCUDNHPPMUDAOOZUCS62FVTC63Z63Q7K5QQJBZVH5LSM2G6WUUTJ3PXQ4IWLJBUSFX3ZOGRSINXVIR67K",
                "supportedInterfaces": {}
            },
            "apiEndpoint": "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com",
            "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5ldS5hbWF6b25hbGV4YS5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJBbGV4YVNraWxsS2l0Iiwic3ViIjoiYW16bjEuYXNrLnNraWxsLjdkOWI2MWE5LTkyZWMtNDc2NS04NGFmLTEzOWUwMzE4YmVlZCIsImV4cCI6MTYyNjEwNTk1MSwiaWF0IjoxNjI2MTA1NjUxLCJuYmYiOjE2MjYxMDU2NTEsInByaXZhdGVDbGFpbXMiOnsiY29udGV4dCI6IkFBQUFBQUFBQVFCMDRZYVF5ZndyME9SaEtSTFFZSWYxVVFFQUFBQUFBQUJyRzE0TjZuNWhUVnhWR0lvalo0RU1Xb2w4THhRcU5rZ0l0ZWNIU3ZWOXFMZ2tpeXBMdVMyYjBVL1NlQTVkOGhoV2dwOS8vSXFvbk1kOXlSM2Y5V2ZIb0FRQXNXZE5KNmxBSm81SkFrYnIvL2JwOFgvbDFhT3IxVkxZY2ZDTEFDZnMwUTU1bU03WWhEcE55RjZDdkNMZlVPdEFRMVp1RFlXK0FHenJZS21uTzlHQk5QYVZGK1R2bmx2NHVvS3hrMHRSc0kydm5BaUxjMkpRRUQ2dVRFOGpNenRBMGFET3lERWsrQmpXbjMvWnpNNHFRZWlra2lZTEtaQ1RNbE5lWDRPdjIrT2VDQ0dCS3JQT0lTMjRsY092YkFwekhuV3FJRTN3TU42S0s5WEhrWUZ3TDBjWTc2amdVWmhWUmMrelhGRzVYa1JmR0lDYmFxQ0liU3ZyN2dpNDl1QXQycHJtQXR0TTZZb2NGbmUrbFgraG1xOE9VR2xVTWpnT01Pb055bStqNnVMU1dSY2dmcFBHSWVFOHRzdUM5OTlBaW9LY0dJZ1FFQ0tPenRYR3oxdlQrS1J6UGc1ZU01N1A3MTVOd1ZLZyIsImNvbnNlbnRUb2tlbiI6IkF0emF8SXdFQklPek5pcFc5OW9USy1NcDlKRnc5b2F3aFd6NjZ3RGQ0YjdXSUlrekRDbEVlOEczU1pTcXpFVUtBVTdocFlUc0p6MU9HcVdsYnZrZXRWZWFneVFFMGFMZWhsTFBueUNqU2dhenBmdEpPR1d4ZHlrMERXWDh5YUs5WWVFTDZieDllbzg2b0NZRGtlUVV3dmJ5c0I1cHVQN3hVaTFFeW5jcjM5NFZKbHBTWTJvaXlMdmtwV1BrU0syZUxCNTRvR0RSS2M5dVluYmRGcUNlZ193YzB0clhtRFpyel9aN0ZGaEdvb2Y1dTh3N3ZuUVZYNUhMTVp1Vnp2UUVKTGxMZDNqdVRLTXQyY1paRU0wSmJ2aW5YNDdZRU5nSVkiLCJkZXZpY2VJZCI6ImFtem4xLmFzay5kZXZpY2UuQUZOTFc3MlFWUTVBUzdBWTdMREZMSlZQNkVUNlZOUjQzU0xSU0NETFVJVE0ySFZEQ1Q1STRLR1FYR1BTVlBLWk9ZVU5IVVkyUzM1WlVGVUdXS0RLNFlNQTdBU0RMVEdRWlZRREtDVUROSFBQTVVEQU9PWlVDUzYyRlZUQzYzWjYzUTdLNVFRSkJaVkg1TFNNMkc2V1VVVEozUFhRNElXTEpCVVNGWDNaT0dSU0lOWFZJUjY3SyIsInVzZXJJZCI6ImFtem4xLmFzay5hY2NvdW50LkFHMkVRMlpLV002NkRTTlFVNDNQVU1NN0VDM0FPU0Q1RzRLVEZYWlczNFBDRFFLRE9MUUY0VUFCNEZTRFBEUzRQQTJFMjZVSkVVWU9JVEtRTzc2V0xLR0xMSlNZSzY1QUgyWEFRTVNKSU9XT0FRRFVaUDc3MzdPTkhEVk9JQjdKV1VQNkpHUjNET05PREZMM0VKUlZXRkFaNzdQWUZOVkZMTEU3VFNKTTNOUFQyUUs3QlBHVVY3NldYN0ZKTkdGVERYQ1BLR1pDNzJOUENCSSJ9fQ.Y7T9qWATCxco__UmwsPyeOovm1VQAhVQFUz3HrF3Q-Cg47wboEnXiPtMmcGpcl0oI5TXHNt29szzEAMwMTYF3TIPAE8GGCfV6QrwyxilBRgRAqOrVp_C8InIz9sjs8BjAjaFbaOcWnkBfso6uHK6bS6TaxMiczynM6IUTsYymDRPlk0bHiCnCUYAmAYOA1blonFgRduuCBEhwcHjYZGOiGG3k0JvW3IsEycOlt3vcdIbcsCjYPITHqfCpjrDzYXXtCSgtPR6u4GlorF_CloPSnB_PSgXz3s_qaqWXwcRGzV5AgwrduWkadNW_YSym4FLt-KuVO_Ygf1aZL0h39uWTw"
        }
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "IntentRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.3a0d2f50-6997-402d-a422-84bf429780db",
        "locale": "en-IN",
        "timestamp": "2021-07-12T16:00:51Z",
        "intent": {
            "name": "GetAddressIntent",
            "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
        }
    }
}
```

Output JSON :

```
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": "<speak>Uh Oh. Looks like something went wrong.</speak>"
            },
            "type": "_DEFAULT_RESPONSE"
        },
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "userAgent": "ask-node/2.7.0 Node/v10.24.1"
    }
}
```

What should I do to improve? I can attach the code too if you guys need it..

Comment: Are you using the simulator to try this? Is your coding receiving an empty response or an error when calling the API? If an error, what's the error stack trace?

Comment: The issue was that I was using it from a simulator.. now it's working well, thanks for offering to help @Andreas